# Unable to scroll a Fragment added dynamically (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I am developing an app where I need to use 2 fragments in an activity. Based on the choice made on the first fragment, the second one will be shown. The problem is that the second fragment is not scrolling down, being cut off by the end of the screen.

Here is the XML of the activity that contains the "fixed" and the the dynamically inserted fragments (`activity_inspection.xml`)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.InspectionActivity"
    android:padding="@dimen/margins">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chooseItemMemorial"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.xxxx.xxxxx.fragments.InspectionMemorial"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_fragment_selected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/chooseItemMemorial"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margins"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is a snippet of one of the fragments that I want to insert dinamically into my activity: (`fragment_external_access.xml`)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.ExternalAccessFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
/** here goes the rest of the code**/
```

EDIT: What I want to achieve is for the first fragment, added via the `<fragment>` tag, to stay fixed on the screen while the second one, added dynamically via code, is able to be scrolled if necessary.

I've tried to use `ScrollView` and `NestedScrollView` without success. But that might be for some silly mistake, like forgetting to add a tag. Since I am new to android programming, every single bit of help will be appreciated.

To end this (and because it might be related), this is the java code I am using to add this fragment:

```java
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_external_access, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the top fragment (First Fragment) can be greedy so that it can take up the entire screen and the reason is that its height is `wrap_content`, so it can take as much as it contains as it lacks of a bottom constraints.

And in this case the bottom fragment can be partially shown or even hidden beneath the screen.

The same applies if the bottom fragment has bigger content, the top fragment will be partially/totally hidden due to the `wrap_content` of the bottom fragment.

So you need to limit the height of both fragments to not use `wrap_content`.

Here I will use `app:layout_constraintHeight_max` attribute for the top fragment, but you have to handle if its contents can be greater than that value; a `ScrollView` is one of the possible options like you did in the Bottom fragment (Second Fragment).

And set the height of both fragments to match constraints.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/margins"
    tools:context=".activities.InspectionActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chooseItemMemorial"
        class="com.xxxx.xxxxx.fragments.InspectionMemorial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_fragment_selected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margins"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/chooseItemMemorial" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So what I need to do with the `<FrameLayout>` is to define a height to it, right? It did work, so thank you so much! I just think this might be a problem when used on different devices with different screen sizes. Is there any way to make a ScrollView scroll without "hardcoding" a size?

Comment: you need to limit the height .. you already defined a height with `wrap_content` .. but the height in this case is variable according to the the contents .. so if the contents is long, then it both fragments can overlap, and probably a fragment can be kicked off the screen .. you can limit the height with the constraints like I did

Comment: @CorMatt You could also share the entire height with both fragments, so that each one can take a half; or even each one can take a percentage .. all that with the constraints... If that made some sense please accept the answer

Comment: Ah, so I can define a percentagem of the screen that can be given for each fragment? I had no idea and I spent almost the entire day looking for it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your scrollview layout_height is set to wrap_content thus expanding to fit all its content. You should set it to match_parent, same goes for the <fragment element.

EDIT: according to new info you could build your layout like below

Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/margins"
    tools:context=".activities.InspectionActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/chooseItemMemorial"
        class="com.xxxx.xxxxx.fragments.InspectionMemorial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margins"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/chooseItemMemorial" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/show_fragment_selected"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragments.ExternalAccessFragment">

/** here goes the rest of the code**/
```

This way the top fragment takes the space it needs (up to 100dp as you specified with app:layout_constraintHeight_max) and the below scrollview takes all the remaining space, which will have the other fragment inside with a wrap_content height.

Comment: Well, it DOES allow the scroll to be created... However what happens is that the second fragment occupies the entire screen, being drawn over the "statically" inserted fragment, like the pic here: [ScreenShot](https://postimg.cc/56xVMDt8)

Comment: So, what you're trying to achieve is 2 fragments stacked on top of each other and the whole page scrolling or one filling a fixed area and the content of the second one scrolling?

Comment: Ah, I should have specified that better, shouldn't I? 
I want that the first fragment (the one created by the `<fragment>` tag stay fixed on the screen while being ableo to scroll up and down the content of the second one.